# Adding Color to a Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

How would you add a draggable that has a specific color, e.g. blue?

I've been using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( function() {
            $( ".box" ).draggable({containment: "parent"});
            $( ".box" ).css("background-color","blue");
        });
    </script>
```

But it shows no change in color, as it stays white. Also, why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = function(color){
  //processing here
return color;
}

        $( function() {
            $( ".box" ).draggable({containment: "parent"});
            $( ".box" ).css("background-color",color("whatever"));
        });
```

you can add some type of logic into the color function to change that color based on whatever you need

Comment: I tried your code, but it didn't seem to work and the color of the div seems to still be white.

Comment: yes, you will need to pass the function an some argument to it and what it returns is a string that contains the color.

Comment: I'm sorry about the edit, and I appreciate the code, but when I try it, it gives me the same problem